# Watson Conversation: Check and act on existence of context variable?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, chatbot, watson-conversation

I am using [IBM Watson Conversation service](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/index.html#about) and slots within a dialog node. In the response I want to return the value of a context variable that is gathered with a slot. However, I cannot be sure that the variable exists because the user could have cancelled the input process and because the variable is optional. How can I check the existence and act depending on that check?

Using this

```
<? $myVariable ?>
```

gives an error when the variable is not present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Conversation service uses Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#accessing-and-evaluating-objects) to process variables and conditions in its responses. There is a special check that can be applied. I have taken the example from this [useful collection of use cases](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#context-variable-defined):

```
"<? context.myVariable? 'Great. I have the following: '+context.myVariable+'.' : 
'No information present' ?>"
```

You can access context variables via `context` followed by the variable name. The question mark (`?`) checks for existence. The first response is taken in the case the variable is present, else the second response. The colon (`:`) separates the two answer options.

In the above example is the answer is either "`Great. I have the following: VALUE`" or "`No information present`".